# Command line argument as size of an array: Compile time or run time?

Tags: c, stack, command-line-arguments, compile-time

So I'm here with a very fundamental question about the stack space. I've read that the variables in the stack have to be known at compile time, but I'm not sure how accurate this is. Let's take this snippet:

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
int numProcesses = argv[1];
int arr[numProcesses] = {};
...
}
```

Naturally, the value of numProcesses, and hence the size of arr[], cannot be known by the compiler at compile time. So how, when and where is arr[numProcesses] allocated? Thanks for what I'm sure would be an insightful answer.

Comment: GCC has an extension to allow variable-length arrays to be allocated on the stack. C99 makes it an official feature of  C.

Comment: One the stack, at runtime. Pretend the compiler calls [`alloca`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca) for you. (Though alloca is a non-standard function)

Comment: Not sure what the downvote is about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I will answer when and how then where.

argc will be done at compile time since it is known what it is then. The compiler will allocate memory for this as a normal variable. The argv is the dynamic part and this will be run time. Again the compiler will allocate the memory for you and, as far as I know, remove it as well.

Since this the amount of memory needed for case argc is known it will be on the stack since its size is known at compile time. argv will be on the heap since it is dynamically allocated at run time as its length is not known beforehand.

Hope this helps!

Comment: When will it remove this memory? Once program execution is over?

Comment: It will remove argc, as I understand it, when the rest of the stack is being deallocated. argv's will be determined by your compiler entirely. Generally your compiler will deallocate the memory after you are not using it anymore if it is clever. It may just remove it at the end either though once it is deallocated it doesn't matter hugely in most cases.